# How to count the number of parameters in a given line within a CSV file

Tags: bash, csv-simple

I've got accumulated data in a CSV file as follows:

```
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4,Parameter_5,Parameter_6
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4,Parameter_5
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
Parameter_1
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
```

How can I just read the the lines which have 4 or more parameters 
i.e:

```
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4,Parameter_5,Parameter_6
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4,Parameter_5
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
  X Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3 X DO NOT READ THIS because it has less than 4 parameters
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
  X Parameter_1 X DO NOT READ THIS because it has less than 4 parameters
Parameter_1,Parameter_2,Parameter_3,Parameter_4
```

Ideally I would like to read lines which have more than 
*X* parameters and less than *Y* parameter - ie not read it if it has too many parameters in a given line

**Q:** How can this be written in BASH?

**?A:** [Should] the code look like this:

```
number_of_parameters=`"$line" | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c` #where $line is the line thats being currently read
if [ "number_of_parameters" -gt "X" ] && [ "number_of_parameters" -lt "Y" ]
then
     ... do something
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep for a much simpler solution.

```
grep -E '^(.*,){3}' my_csv_file.csv
```

Since 4 parameters or more will have at least 3 commas, hence the 3 in the regex.

**(.*,)** will match a parameter followed by a comma. **.*** means match any char (.) 0 or more times.

Here's another approach to have the values in a variable:

```
my_var=$(grep -E '^(.*,){3}' my_csv_file.csv)
echo "$my_var"
```

Make sure you have "" around $my_var otherwise you will lose the newlines.

Comment: Any chance you could explain what `^(.*,)` does? Also how would I assign this to a variable?

Comment: Edited the answer with explanation

Comment: How about assigning the value to a variable? my_var=`grep -E '^(.*,){3}' my_csv_file.csv`

Comment: Doing so will not preserve the newlines. And assigning to a variable is not recommended because if the csv file is multi gigabytes, your script might throw a memory error. Still if you want to assign to a variable another approach is required.

Comment: I don't think the `my_csv_file.csv` file will exceed 100MB over the next 2 years. What would be another approach to combating this? The reason why I want a variable - is so that I can compare the`my_var` variable ie `if` the `my_var` is `-gt 3` go ahead read the file `if` not try again

Comment: Edited my answer again

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation and guidance.

Comment: How is a `grep` solution simpler than using a tool that is designed for such task, like `awk`? (See my answer for details.)

Comment: @3kstc  - as usual, people have to guess what you're actually trying to do there... If data is constantly being added to your file you should tail-follow the appended lines and _do something_ only if a line has a certain number of fields. There's no point reading the whole file over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

This is of course not a task that should be solved with `sed`, `grep`, or similar, but rather naturally with `awk`. To filter lines in a file with at least 4 (comma-separated) fields:

```
awk -F, 'NF>=4' my_csv_file.csv
```

To filter lines with, e.g., at least 4 and at most 6 (comma-separated) fields:

```
awk -F, 'NF>=4 && NF<=6' my_csv_file.csv
```